# No puedo abrir la aplicación

Tags: java, android, selenium, selenium-webdriver, appium

Hola a tod@s estoy intentando hacer una prueba de automatizar con `appium`.
He probado en una aplicación interna "calculadora", pero me da un error de ruta pero no lo veo.
A ver si me podéis ayudar. 
Aquí os dejo mi código java:

```
public class Testapp {
    public static AndroidDriver<MobileElement> driver;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException {
        String projectPath = System.getProperty("user.dir");
        System.out.println(projectPath);
        File app = new File (projectPath + "\\app\\selendroid-test-app-0.17.0.apk");
        System.out.println(app);
        //browser + Devices
        DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();

        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "Android");

        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, "Android");

        cap.setCapability(AndroidMobileCapabilityType.APP_PACKAGE, "com.android.calculator2");


        cap.setCapability(AndroidMobileCapabilityType.APP_ACTIVITY, ".Calculadora");

        driver = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), cap);


         Thread.sleep(3000);


        driver.quit();


    }
```

Aquí el fallo:

```
remote stacktrace: UnknownError: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Cannot start the 'com.android.calculator2' application. Visit https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/writing-running-appium/android/activity-startup.md for troubleshooting. Original error: Activity name '.Calculadora' used to start the app doesn't exist or cannot be launched! Make sure it exists and is a launchable activity
    at getResponseForW3CError (C:\Users\x57119ga\AppData\Local\Programs\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-base-driver\lib\protocol\errors.js:826:9)
    at asyncHandler (C:\Users\x57119ga\AppData\Local\Programs\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-base-driver\lib\protocol\protocol.js:447:37)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'CR3533006DC0109', ip: '192.168.0.19', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_65'
Driver info: driver.version: AndroidDriver
```

Comment: `Activity name '.Calculadora' used to start the app doesn't exist` es un casi autoexplicativo. Revisaste ésto?

Comment: Define el paquete completo donde se encuentra la Activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error indica:

> Activity name '.Calculadora' used to start the app doesn't exist or
>   cannot be launched! Make sure it exists and is a launchable activity

que no existe la `Activity` '.Calculadora', te sugiero definir en la capability que indica la activity, el paquete donde se encuentra la `Activity`.

Suponiendo que se encuentra dentro de `com.android.calculator2.Calculator`, definelo de esta forma:

```
//cap.setCapability(AndroidMobileCapabilityType.APP_ACTIVITY, ".Calculadora");
 cap.setCapability(AndroidMobileCapabilityType.APP_ACTIVITY, "com.android.calculator2.Calculadora");
```